# Hawtio terminal plugin for Karaf 4.0.2

Tags: apache-karaf, karaf, hawtio

I have installed Apache Karaf 4.0.2 and Hawtio 1.456. The installation of Hawtio worked fine. But when I do bundle:list I see the "hawtio :: Karaf terminal plugin" in a failure state. However the hawtio functionality seems to be working.

Is it an incompatibility issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The terminal plugin has not yet been migrated to karaf 3.x/4.x as they changed the apis in karaf in a breaking way.

They did the same for the logger, which we had to do a fair amount of code to get working again.

So wait for a future release of hawtio where we have migrated the terminal plugin.

And hopefully the karaf guys dont break more stuff in future releases.

I logged a ticket: https://github.com/hawtio/hawtio/issues/2028

Comment: Thanks Claus, I kind of suspected that. I saw a video about Karaf 4.0 where they have redone a lot of the code. Hopefully the core parts stay stable for the coming releases. Thanks again.